# how to read draw search tree from tracing in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to draw a search tree from a query in prolog. I used the tracing function in Swish, but I still don't know how to write out a search tree on pen and paper to fully understand it. 
[Here is the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9rf4.png)
Thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Do you know the basic of unification ?

Comment: @mcnight Yeah i know the basics of it.

Comment: This is a very simple predicate with just a couple of facts. The purpose of the assignment is to show your understanding of how Prolog unification works. To do the search tree, start with the query, and walk through its execution manually, step by step. If you're not sure what happens at a particular step, then ask about that specifically. Here you're query is `jealous(X, Y).` what does Prolog do with it? it will find the first fact or predicate that it can unify with. Start from there.